# Deadlock during static initialization

Tags: gcc, boost, solaris

I'm running into a deadlock during static initialization in Solaris.  The situation strongly resembles that of [this user's problem](http://lists.opencsw.org/pipermail/users/2012-July/009270.html).

My environment is:

- solaris 10
- gcc 5.4 installed to a non-standard location
- all relevant shared libraries are linked against the libstdc++ and/or libgcc_s libraries from that installation
- boost 1.45 (we're moving away from it soon, but for the moment that cannot change)
- I see this problem when linking dynamically *or* statically against boost libraries

The symptoms:

- Deadlocks while executing `boost::system::generic_category()`
- `generic_category()` is being called to initialize global static references in `boost/system/error_code.hpp`
- If I shuffle link order, putting -lboost_system ahead of other libraries being linked in, the problem goes away.
- If I set a breakpoint in `generic_category()` then attempt to step over the 1st line after the first time the breakpoint gets hit, the breakpoint gets hit again when executing the same function in a different shared library's `_init()` -- that is, it never stops on the 2nd line of `generic_category()` from when I told it to step over the 1st line.

Since stepping over the 1st line didn't work, I stepped into it then stepped out & again the breakpoint got hit.

I restarted the process & stepped in after the breakpoint got hit then began stepping.  Stepping over the call to `boost::system::error_category::error_category()` I ran into the same problem.

I tried again, this time stepping an instruction at a time when I got to the `error_category()` call.  It attempts to call it through the PLT which calls `elf_rtbndr()` which is supposed to return the real function's address in `%o0`, but when I step over the call to `elf_rtbndr()` it again hits the breakpoint instead of resuming where it left off.

When the breakpoint gets hit for the 2nd time it's calling `generic_category()` in some other shared library's `_init()`; that's when the deadlock occurs.

Thanks in advance for your time & help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been reported several times (see [this post in Boost](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2013/01/200468.php) and [another in GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2013-01/msg00179.html)). This seems to be a circular dependency issue during Boost initialization which, for some reason, only manifests on Solaris. The usual advice is to work around this by messing with library initialization (e.g. by shuffling the library order as you did with `-lboost_system`).

Another option is to disable thread-safe guards (`-fno-threadsafe-statics` flag) which would get rid of the deadlock but would keep the buggy nested constructor call which is undesirable.

Comment: I suggest to report a bug to Boost, this really sounds like a bug in the implementation.

Comment: My bet is it's already fixed in more recent versions of boost.  We've been stuck using Sun Studio for many years.  Getting our code to build with the more recent (supposedly gcc compatible) version of Sun Studio would prove annoying (among other things, it doesn't quite do a good enough job pretending to be gcc to fool the gauntlet of `#ifdef` macros in boost), so we're just going to drop sun studio support then jump to a more recent version of boost; but in the mean-time ...